# Account Password Insert Process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I wanted to discover new points in ASP.NET MVC ecosystem. So I wanted to try something.

It's a sign up system.
4 tables (but there are 7 tables. you will see below.)
by the way, i am working with DatabaseFirst style.

My models:

```
    public partial class AccountInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateSignUp { get; set; }
        public string FacebookId { get; set; }
        public string TwitterId { get; set; }
        public string InstagramId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AccountPasswordOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class AccountAuth
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int PasswordOrderId { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class AccountPassword1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class AccountPassword2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class AccountPassword3
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class AccountPassword4
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

So that's my structure.
in my code,

1. I'm inserting into `AccountInfo` table then getting its Id as `AccountId`,
2. then
3. I'm creating a List with randomized order (1,2,3,4 - 2,3,1,4 - 3,4,2,1 etc..)
4. I'm inserting into `AccountPasswordOrder` table then getting its Id as `PasswordOrderId`,
5. then
6. I'm inserting into `AccountAuth` table with values (`AccountId`, `Email` and `PasswordOrderId`)
7. I'm crypting the password into SHA1 (40 characters)
8. then
9. exploding the password into 4 pieces as below

   ```
   string Password_1 = Form_Password.Substring(0, 10);
   string Password_2 = Form_Password.Substring(10, 10);
   string Password_3 = Form_Password.Substring(20, 10);
   string Password_4 = Form_Password.Substring(30, 10);
   ```

then
I don't know what to do.
because i don't know how i can do this:

```
foreach (var item in PasswordOrderList)
{
    string TableName = "AccountPassword" + item;
    //how can i use TableName string variable for 
    //AccountPassword1 AccountPassword1Object=new AccountPassword1();
    //AccountPassword1Object.AccountId=..
    //AccountPassword1Object.Password=Password_+item;
    //DB.AccountPassword1.Add(AccountPassword1);
    //DB.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple tables for multiple passwords?  Just have one table that holds multiple passwords for each user.

Comment: better to use switch case OR If statement, if your password list has 4 password length

Comment: @Luke there is only 1 password in SHA1 format(40 characters length). i created 4 parts as .Substring(0, 10), .Substring(10, 10); .Substring(20, 10); .Substring(30, 10);. i want to store them randomized ordered different tables. just for a security detail.

Comment: @SandipPatel but too many possibilities.

Comment: You're not making anything more secure by doing this. Choose a hashing mechanism that is secure rather than inventing your own.  Storing an insecure password hash in multiple tables doesn't add additional security.  A secure password hash is so far removed from the original password and that is what makes it secure.  Not some wacky way of storing the hash :).

Comment: password split and store it not main concern over here, the main concern is define dynamic class and object

Comment: @luke my goal is developing and while developing learning new things. in my opinion i can increase the security here by storing sha1 password in different and randomized ordered tables.

Comment: @sandip patel yes my concern is using dynamic tables while storing.

Comment: I agree that we should concentrate on storing the data dynamically.  But you're not increasing the security of anything, because if the hash is secure then it is meaningless information just used for verification purposes.

Comment: 1. SHA1, in fact all hash functions, are not encryption, they are one-way functions. 2. What you are adding is just obfuscation which does not add security. 3. In order to secure hashed passwords iteration is needed in order to show down brute force attacks. 4. Use well vetted security methods, it is not easy to get security correct. 5. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)
Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this provides nothing in the way of additional security, I've been pondering how this might be achieved and I wonder if the following may be possible:

```
var passwords = new List<string>();

passwords.Add(Form_Password.Substring(0, 10));
passwords.Add(Form_Password.Substring(0, 10));
passwords.Add(Form_Password.Substring(10, 10));
passwords.Add(Form_Password.Substring(20, 10));
passwords.Add(Form_Password.Substring(30, 10));

var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

for (var i = 0; i < passwords.Count(); i++)
{
    // Get the password section to store
    var passwordString = passwords[i];

    // Generate fully qualified namespace of the EF object that represents the table, inserting the password count number
    var tableName = string.Format("Namespace.To.EntityFramework.AutoGenerated.Objects.AccountPassword{0}, Assemblyname", i + 1);

    // Get the type using fully qualified namespace
    var tableType = Type.GetType(tableName);

    // Get instance of type and assign to dynamic
    dynamic password = Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);

    // Set the properties of the object
    password.Password = passwordString;

    // other properties...
    // password.AccountId = 100;

    // Add them to the DbContext
    var dbContext.Set(tableType).Add(password);
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### Getting the fully qualified namespace of your class

Say for instance, one of your classes is in a project called `MyProject`.  The DLL that is generated when you build your project is `MyProject.dll`.

Here's your class that was auto generated by Entity Framework, because you're using EF database first:

```
namespace MyAmazingApp.Entities
{
    public partial class AccountPassword1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The fully qualified namespace of this class is:

> MyAmazingApp.Entities.AccountPassword1, MyProject

So you'd need to replace the value in `string.Format()` to that, eg:

```
// Generate fully qualified namespace of the EF object that represents the table, inserting the password count number
var tableName = string.Format("MyAmazingApp.Entities.AccountPassword{0}, MyProject", i + 1);
```

Comment: tabletype is null, sorry.

Comment: Yeah it will be. You need to replace the fully qualified namespace that is valid for your application.  It's the namespace and assembly of your entity framework models

Comment: you are right. i think objecttype must be tabletype right ? it is still null.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Yes it will be null because I just put `Namespace.To.EntityFramework.AutoGenerated.Objects.AccountPassword{0}` as the value as an arbitrary value.  You need to get the fully qualified namespace of your auto generated Entity Framework classes `AccountPassword1`, `AccountPassword2`.  This is because what is happening is `Type.GetType()` uses the namespace information to create an instance of a class that you have in _your_ project.

Comment: I've added my info to the answer to help you :)